# Flutter TextField only positive numbers

Tags: flutter, textfield

Is there a way in flutter to make a TextField only accept numbers greater than zero? I currently only allow numbers via the following code:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
```

Now I want to prevent the TextField to have the value zero while still generally allowing to type zeros. Thus, allowing to enter 100 and preventing to enter 001.

I don't want to achieve this by listening to input changes and then manually erasing zeros, or by similar methods. I am looking for a built-in solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`digitsOnly` calls `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]'))`

so just replace it with `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^[1-9][0-9]*'))`

Answer (score 1):

add this code to `TextFormField`

`inputFormatters:[FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[0-9]"))],`

it works for me.